# Build axvlc.cab to allow installation of plugin without internet access (on intranet)

Tags: plugins, activex, vlc, cab

I have the following task: Provide VLC plugins locally so that they can be installed even if a user doesn't have internet access (no VLC installed, only intranet access).

The axvlc.cab file is unfortunately not available anymore from the VLC website (as described [here](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=97518&start=20)).

There are some instructions in the VLC forum (e.g. [here](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=98424&p=329958#p329960)), and I understand that there's also a ton of resources about creating .cab files.

However, I'm wondering what the absolutely shortest path is to achieve this for this particular VLC plugin. I probably should also mention that I haven't done anything with CAB files etc. in the past.

I checked the last available axvlc.cab v0.8.6 (available [here](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/0.8.6/win32/)), and it appears that it basically only contains a "link" to the installer. I'm wondering if it would be enough to:
 - Make the installer available on my own server
 - Rewrite the .inf file in the .cab to point it to that "local installer" instead of the one available on the VLC website?

The next best idea would be to take the axvlc.dll and create the cab file on my own. Not sure what the exact steps for that would be. I understand that the Microsoft Cabinet SDK isn't really what Microsoft supports/recommends anymore. Although it's still available on some 3rd party website (e.g. [this one](http://www.pixelsplasher.com/_downloads/software/Microsoft-Cabinet-SDK/)), the way to go about creating .cab files is via Visual Studio, right?

Also, do I absolutely have to sign the .cab file I'm going to re-create, or will it work (assuming I add the site to trusted sites or what not) if it's not signed? I'd like to just get it working first before I get a cert etc.

The 2nd part of the exercise, namely to provide the .xpi plugin for Mozilla and Chrome as well, seems easier as VLC still provides this one on their [website](http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/).

But if somebody could provide html code how to embed the FF plugin and make it download from a local directory on that same server if not installed yet, I'd appreciate it too.